# Read and use image requested from url in Python

Tags: python, io, python-requests, google-vision

I'm currently trying to work with Google's python vision library. But I'm currently stuck on how to read images from the web. So far I've got this here down below. My issue is that the contents always seem to be empty and when I check using PyCharm, it says that it only contains `b''`.

How can I open this image so I can use it for Google's library?

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from urllib import request
import io

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_json('cred.json')

url = "https://cdn.getyourguide.com/img/location_img-59-1969619245-148.jpg"

img = request.urlopen(url)
with io.open('location_img-59-1969619245-148.jpg', 'rb') as fhand:
    content = fhand.read()
image = types.Image(content=content)
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

Comment: To make things simpler, try to save the image locally and use its absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try get image via [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library?

```
import requests 

r = requests.get("https://cdn.getyourguide.com/img/location_img-59-1969619245-148.jpg") 
o = open("location_img.jpg", "wb")
o.write(r.content)
o.close()
```